# Dragging a rotated container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Normally, to drag a container or an image around the screen I would do this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: TestComp(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestComp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestCompState createState() => _TestCompState();
}

class _TestCompState extends State<TestComp> {
  double _y = 0;
  double _x = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: _y,
          left: _x,
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: math.pi / 180 * 0,
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.black,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanUpdate: (details) {
                        var dx = details.delta.dx;
                        var dy = details.delta.dy;
                        setState(() {
                          _y += dy;
                          _x += dx;
                        });
                      },
                      child:
                          Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

This works perfectly fine. However, when I rotate this container to say -136 degrees, it doesn't move correctly.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: TestComp(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestComp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestCompState createState() => _TestCompState();
}

class _TestCompState extends State<TestComp> {
  double _y = 0;
  double _x = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: _y,
          left: _x,
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: math.pi / 180 * -136,
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.black,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanUpdate: (details) {
                        var dx = details.delta.dx;
                        var dy = details.delta.dy;
                        setState(() {
                          _y += dy;
                          _x += dx;
                        });
                      },
                      child:
                          Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

My requirement here is to have `Transform.rotate` on Stack>Positioned. The inner stack can have many more elements so I want the GestureDetector to be only inside image because the coordinates should only be updated when the image is moved. Please help me with this.

Comment: You have to consider that when you're moving your widget, the transform doesn't change horizontal to vertical constraints. You have to check where your widget is facing, and detect where to move it according to the rotated position

Comment: @JuanCurti I am weak with coordinates calculation. If possible can you like show me a sample or a diagram that demonstrates it for me to understand? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there was problem in GestureDetector it was getting x and y value rotated -136 degree

just place gesture detector above Transform Widget Than it will take correct x and
y values

your error is solved

```
        void main() {
      debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
      return runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            body: SafeArea(
              child: TestComp(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class TestComp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _TestCompState createState() => _TestCompState();
    }
    
    class _TestCompState extends State<TestComp> {
      double _y = 0;
      double _x = 0;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: _y,
              left: _x,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  var dx = details.delta.dx;
                  var dy = details.delta.dy;
                  setState(() {
                    _y += dy;
                    _x += dx;
                  });
                },
                child: Transform.rotate(
                  angle: math.pi / 180 * -136,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: 300,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Positioned(
                          top: 0,
                          left: 0,
                          child: Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/300x200"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: But the inner stack can have many more elements, so shouldn’t the GestureDetector be only for image since the coordinates should only be updated when the image is moved? @rishabhmistry

Comment: in current code its on Image itself i have just changed the parent widget Hierarchy,
your stack current have one widget only whose top parent widget is POsitioned 
your code and my code is same i have just changed parent Hierarchy,

Comment: Yeah I’m sorry I didn’t mention but the inner stack can have many more elements so coordinates should only be updated when the image is dragged. @rishabhmistry